# How to "flatten" images when printing from browser?

Tags: html, image, pdf, printing, flatten

We have web pages that we want to allow the user to print. A page may include images that we wish to "protect". We employ several techniques to prevent a naive user from "copying" images off the web page.

When the user prints, one option the browser offers is "print to PDF". We have no way to prevent this. The problem is, the PDF is composed of discrete images so any user can individually select and copy the images out of the PDF.

We hoped using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) would solve the problem, but while it made a nice canvas object, printing the canvas did not "flatten" the constituent images. (they could still be selected and copied)

How have other folks protected images on their webpages while still allowing the user to print them?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate stylesheet (something like print.css) which will display a different layout/styles for printers. You can use display:none; for your discreet images.

This article should give a good explanation on how to set that up.
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: Thanks. But, as the question asked, we need to PRINT the images. We just don't want them discreet in the browser-generated PDF.

Answer (score 0):

html2canvas did exactly what we wanted... after we fixed our bugs in how we used it.

We build up the dom in our usual way, then we call html2canvas to "snapshot" the portion of the screen we want the user to print. When done correctly, all of our images are collapsed into a single image and if the user print to PDF, they cannot pull them apart.

Our bug was in not correctly removing all the images from the dom AFTER the conversion. Thus they were getting streamed into the PDF discretely.